# Vue Does not Rendering array update view when the array value is changed

Tags: vue.js

Vue app uses `v-for` for rendering the array or list normally.
This is an example.
[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gzvrLny2/8/)

```js
 new Vue({
  el:'#mainapp',
  data:{
    items:[0,0, 0]
  },
  methods:{
    updateVaule:function(index){
      this.items[index]++;
      alert('current value'+this.items[index]);
    }
  }
})

//Html file
```

```html
    <div id="mainapp">
      <span v-for="(item,index) in items" v-on:click="updateVaule(index)">{{item}}</span>
    </div>
```

But when the user clicking the `span` tag, the view is not updated though value of `items` had been changed.
I've tried to add `v-bind:key=index` to the `span` tag, but this didn't affect anything.
To render the updated array, how does the app have to work?
What am I wrong?

Comment: @GhostCat, what do I have to do?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. In this example, the question should have been closed, as off topic for example. It really doesn't belong on SO. So, I am only asking to be really thoughtful when voting EDIT on triage. You see, if the majority votes "edit", then others are asked to edit. Which is pointless with questions that can't be fixed by editing. That is all there is to this. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Vue's `$set` method to change the array elements.

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#mainapp',
  data:{
    items:[0,0, 0]
  },
  methods:{
    updateVaule:function(index){
      this.$set(this.items, index, this.items[index] + 1)
      alert('current value'+this.items[index]);
    }
  }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exilod/p1mvy7xb/1/)

More info on `$set` method and reactivity in depth [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: As explained in Common Beginner Gotchas(https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating), you should use array methods like push, splice or whatever and never modify the indexes like this a[index] = 1 nor the .length property of an array. Since the abandonment of Object.observe and Array.observe, vue can't pick the changes made the way you did (here is where the $set method comes in).